# I’m a / one hundred percent sure

Tags: difference

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> - I’m **one** hundred percent sure.
> - I’m **a** hundred percent sure.

For me the only difference between the two sentences is that the second sentence is more formal.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/923/difference-between-hundred-a-hundred-and-one-hundred

Comment: The former is [a little more common](http://bit.ly/1yPxpkx), but have roughly the same meaning.

Comment: Wow, I'm surprised; thanks for that, Tim.  Subjectively I felt that “a hundred percent” would be more common.  But even when I removed the “sure” and limited to British or American English, “one hundred percent” came on top.  I may need to reconsider my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The two phrases have the same basic meaning, but native speakers tend to use the "one hundred percent sure" wording in order to to give a greater impression of certainty. In speech, you can emphasise the word "one" more strongly than "a" and the phrase is spoken with a regular rhythm as ONE HUNdred perCENT SURE.

Answer (score 5):

There is no difference. However, I have heard the former *more frequently*. Maybe, in India though.

[OALD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/hundred) defines it:

> *a/one hundred percent* - in every way.

Comment: Thanks Maulik; but I heard using 'one' in this sense is nit common at least as using the determiner 'a'. Have you ever heard or read something about it somewhere? :-/

Comment: Nima, I searched. Both are in use. Right now I'm away and on mobile. May get back to you.

Answer (score 3):

“One hundred percent” is more emphatic. When spoken, the stress naturally falls on “one”. But other than that, they are completely equivalent. A similar emphasis can be achieved with “a *hundred* percent” by stressing the quantity “hundred”.

Note the examples given in [Oxford Learners Dictionaries](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/hundred):

- *I'm not a hundred per cent sure.*
- *My family supports me one hundred per cent.*
- *I still don't feel a hundred per cent.*

The statement about having family support is stronger than the other two.

“I still don't feel one hundred percent” is not incorrect, but feels more awkward when spoken.  A native speaker would more likely use “a hundred” here, as in the dictionary example. Perhaps “don't feel a hundred percent (well)” means “don't feel quite well”; but “don't feel one hundred percent” or “don't feel a *hundred* percent” mean “don't feel completely well”?

“Not 100% sure” is an interesting case. Because of the negation, you would normally use the softer “a hundred” form. To me, “I'm not a hundred percent sure” means “I'm not very sure”; whereas “I'm not *one hundred* percent sure” means “I'm reasonably sure but not *completely* certain” (with the spoken stress on the words in italic/oblique font).

This is not a distinction that I see in the affirmative “I am a/one hundred percent sure”. Both mean “completely sure”.  It's only a difference in emphasis, not degree.

There's also a third written form that I've slipped in above: “100%”.  Here, *100* can be pronounced *a hundred* or *one hundred*, and the writer is giving no indication as to which.

[Acknowledgement to Maulik and David, I've drawn on their answers in formulating this one.]

Answer (score 0):

I tend to say “I’m a hundred . . .” but that may be because of my Southern U.S. tendency to slur over certain word landscapes, so to speak.